# How to use two Dockerfile in one docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
version: '2'

services:
  service1:
    build:
    image: company/service1:v1
    context: .
      - dockerfile: Dockerfile-service1

  service2:
    build: .
    image: company/service2:v1
    links:
      - service1
```

I have two Dockerfiles, one is called Dockerfile and one is called Dockerfile-service1 both in the same directory  (`/opt`) as the `docker-compose.yml`.

I need to build both images and start the containers and link them. In order for me to do that now, I move the `Dockerfile-service1` into another directory and rename it to Dockerfile and then run the build command like this: docker build -t `company/service1:v1` .

Then I go to the /opt directory again and build the service2 image and start both containers: `docker build . --no-cache -t company/service2:v1 && docker-compose up -d`

There must be a better way so I can run one command that does both, I just don't know how.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure what are you trying to do, but you do not need to rename docker file. In docker-compose, you can have it like this:

```
build: 
  context: ./path_to_dockerfile 
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-service1
```

and then I run everything inside docker-compose.yml with following command:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Prashanth Sams and @golobich, Worked beautifully. Thanks much!

Comment: If this is solved, then please accept the answer, so future users will know what help you to fix this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This would do:

```
version: '2'

services:
  service1:
    container_name: service1
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-service1

  service2:
    container_name: service2
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    links:
      - service1
```

or if you have the `service-2` image already built, here it is:

```
version: '2'

services:
  service1:
    container_name: service1
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-service1

  service2:
    container_name: service2
    image: company/service2:v1
    links:
      - service1
```

```
docker-compose up -d
```